# Can a wp_nonce created from domain 1 to be verified on domain 2?

Tags: ajax, nonce

From the Domain 1 i want to make an AJAX request to Domain 2.

I would like to create a `wp_nonce` on Domain 1 and send it with AJAX request to Domain 2, then verify it on Domain 2.

The 2 domains are on 2 different servers. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Nonce is generated on server as a function of  domain name, user information, action, time, etc.

This is made especially to distinguish requests from one server to another.